# UploadServiceDefinition_server to ArcGIS Server not working on IIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, asp.net, iis, service-definition

I want to write a web using MVC that uploads a .sd file to my ArcGIS Server using Python (arcpy). In my controller I have:

```
public string upload_sd()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\python.exe";
            string add = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/Python/uploadsd.py");
            String[] args = new string[] { add};
            Debug.WriteLine(args[0]);
            start.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", args[0]);
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            string result;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

in uploadsd.py I have:

```
import arcpy
try:
    arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(r'RAIN17242.sd', r'arcgis on 10.0.0.201_6080 (publisher).ags')
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

When I publish my web to the IIS server, script does not stop and when I check my ArcGIS Server Manager, nothing is published.

When I run the script using the command prompt, it works fine.

Comment: This question is right on the border of stackoverflow and gis.stackexchange. Essentially you need help debugging your webservice that happens to be calling a Python script that happens to be calling arcpy. That in itself seems a bit much, but I'll defer to the fact you probably have a good reason. Anyways, best guess: the service that calls python (which calls arcpy) probably doesn't have the permissions or rights to launch everything it needs, including the import of arcpy.

Comment: Actually, I'll back out my statement "you probably a good reason", and say here is a "better way" (if you really need to roll your own uploader) would be to call into the Publish tools that run on the Server. That is what the UploadServiceDefinition tool on Desktop does. So, you just need to write a service that handles file upload and passes the appropriate parameters. That removes a whole tier of python/arcpy.

Comment: @KHibma thank you for your comments. Actually, when I run the website for debugging on iisexpress, everything works fine. Also, arcpy is loading completely. I can use almost any other tool. But when i use UploadServiceDefinition_server and publish my web to my IIS server, uploading the sd file and publishing the map service process does not stop. Do you have any idea why this happens?